# How to add a dynamic appends to a model in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-4

To start, let me explain my DB schema.

The important part for this question is I have 3 tables:

- components
- codes
- component_codes (that acts as a pivot table for the relationship between the two)

Components and Codes are in a ManyToMany relationship.

I've got restful API set up in the `/components/index/` route that looks like this:

```
  {
    "id": "49",
    "name": "Gloves",
    "thumb": "img\/product.jpg",
    "filter_id": "9",
    "active": "1",
    "created_at": "2014-01-10 17:45:00",
    "updated_at": "2014-01-10 17:45:00",
    "codes": [
      {
        "id": "4",
        "code": "asd123",
        "specs": "10x10cm",
        "packing": "100",
        "active": "1",
        "created_at": "2014-01-06 16:19:26",
        "updated_at": "2014-01-06 16:19:26",
        "pivot": {
          "component_id": "49",
          "code_id": "4"
        }
      }
  }
```

I now want to append two values to the "codes" child json object which will have the value of that object's parent. In this case, I need the "codes" array to have the value `"name": "Gloves"` and `"thumb": "img\/product.jpg"`. Essentially duplicating it's parent's data.

So far I have this:

**models/Code.php**

```
<?php

class Code extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'codes';
    protected $appends = array('parent_name', 'parent_img_url');

    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array();

    public function components()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Component', 'component_codes', 'component_id', 'code_id');
    }

    public function getParentNameAttribute()
    {
        $parent = Component::find(50);
        return $parent->name_en;
    }

    public function getParentImgUrlAttribute()
    {
        $parent = Component::find(50);
        return $parent->thumb;
    }

}
```

This works as expected, but it's not dynamic, the ID of the component is hard coded in (ie: 50). I need this to be the ID of the component in question.

Hope I made myself clear, if not, please let me know in the comments.

**Edit:** Another solution would be to add those values to the pivot table laravel creates. Right now there's only the component_id and the code_id in it. If there's anyway to add a the component's name to it as well it would fit my needs.

Comment: Where is your parent_id? You need a parent_id in your table if you want to access it...

Comment: The parent ID is in the pivot table named component_codes which was created by the Many to Many relationship in Laravel. Is there anyway I access it in the Codes model?

Answer (score 0):

It's a many to many relation, so you might have many records, but you can do this, to get the first one:

```
public function getParentNameAttribute()
{
    $parent = $this->components()->first();

    return $parent->name_en;
}
```

You might need to explain better your structure/schema so people here understands what you need. Makes no sense a

```
Component::find($id);
```

To return a name from a many to many table.

This is how you deal with many to many tables:

```
public function getWhateverYouNeed()
{
    foreach($this->components as $component)
    {
        // do whatever you need with them
    }

    /// return whatever you need
}
```

Comment: Olá Antonio. I edited the OP to try and explain better my situation, thanks for the tip. Regarding your answer, I get "Trying to get property of non-object" on your first solution, and an empty array when I try this: http://laravel.io/bin/a1vB